# Connectedness of subsets of topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$, $B$ be closed subsets of topological space $X$. Given that $A\cup B$ and, $A\cap B$ are both connected.  How can we show that both A, B are connected?
This is in general not true for any subsets of $X$. I can't construct a counter example.  I mean,  both $A$, $B$ must be closed for this.
What happens when they are open?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206840/a-cup-b-and-a-cap-b-connected-implies-a-and-b-are-connected?rq=1

Comment: And also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727407/suppose-that-v-w-are-closed-in-x-and-that-v-cap-w-v-cup-w-are-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks...i got the answer